How to paste files in "/usr/share folder" in Ubuntu 22.04 WSL?
To execute a program, I need to paste some files from a Windows folder to a subfolder of /usr/share on Ubuntu 22.04 WSL. However, the /usr folder and its subfolders are read only.
How to fix this issue? Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Too few details to offer useful advice. Maybe there are better alternatives than mucking about in /usr/share.

This is not an issue. This is normal behavior.
(1) /usr/share is a system directory. (2) Moreover, it is managed by the system. Two very good reasons why normal users should not modify this directory.
With respect to (1), one must be administrator of the system to be allowed to modify system directories. With respect to (2), if files are to be manually installed, an administrator will place these files in /usr/local/share rather than /usr/share. The directories under local have the same use as the corresponding ones under /usr but are specifically intended for locally managed software such as user-compiled programs or manually copied binaries.
Thus, (1) make sure you are the administrator of the system, or consult your system administrator; (2) consider installing these files under /usr/local/share rather than under /usr/share

We assume you want to install new wallpapers or a theme? Do it as root:
sudo cp <file1> <file2> <file3> /usr/share/path/to/folder

Then log out and log back in to your session to validate.
